# Regex string detection unless a specific pattern is detected using lookarounds in R

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, regex-lookarounds, stringr

I'm looking to highlight a pattern in a string unless another pattern is also detected using regex for later string processing. Ultimatly, I'm looking to replace all the `hat` or `hats` with a `space` unless `what` or `no` are found within the string but am using detection during the pattern trial.

Data:

```
require(tidyverse)

trial.string<-c("Hat","coif","hatter","HATS","plushy","no hat","what","hat no","hats","HAT, what","what, hat, no, hats","A water hat")
```

So far I've attempted to use the following pattern in `str_view_all` to check if it works. I used the `regex` function for the `ignore_case = TRUE` option.

```
trial.string %>% 
  str_view_all(regex("(?<!w)hat(s)*(?!.*(what|no))"
                     ,ignore_case = TRUE))
```

Which results in:

[image]

The end result should be exclude the sixth string `no hat` and eleventh string `what, hat, no, hats` from being detected.

I'm not sure if I'm using the lookarounds in the right way for this to work or it's my use of the `regex` function which is wrong.

Comment: How long are the strings? If they are not too long, use `stringr::str_replace_all(trial.string, "(?i)(?<!\\b(?:no|what)\\b.{0,1000})\\bhats?(?!.*\\b(?:no|what)\\b)", " ")`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, a quantifier in a look-behind assertion?

Comment: @Israel Girón-Palacios, it seems that it is no task for a single regular expression. I suggest another approach: screen the lines with "what" or "no" with the first regular expression (save them in an array and replace with some escape sequence containing the array index), then remove "hat" with the second regex, then unscreen the screened lines with the third regex.

Comment: @AlexanderMashin Yes, it is allowed in ICU regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for following up. I was only able to take a quick glance at thew `str_view_all` at this time, due to some circumstances from my end, but it seems to do the trick quite well. Thanks.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Will do. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following ICU regex with an assumption you can't have more than 1K chars between `no` and `what` words and `hat` word:

```
stringr::str_replace_all(trial.string, 
      "(?i)(?<!\\b(?:no|what)\\b.{0,1000})\\bhats?(?!.*\\b(?:no|what)\\b)", " ")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sCGjK2/1).

It matches:

- `(?i)` - case insensitive mode on
- `(?<!\b(?:no|what)\b.{0,1000})` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a whole word `no` or `what` followed with any zero to 1000 chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `\bhat` - word boundary and `hat` string
- `s?` - an optional `s`
- `(?!.*\b(?:no|what)\b)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible (`.*`) followed with a whole word `no` or `what`.

See an [R demo online](https://ideone.com/8x0K5m):

```
trial.string<-c("Hat","coif","hatter","HATS","plushy","no hat","what","hat no","hats","HAT, what","what, hat, no, hats","A water hat")
stringr::str_replace_all(trial.string, 
      "(?i)(?<!\\b(?:no|what)\\b.{0,1000})\\bhats?(?!.*\\b(?:no|what)\\b)", " ")
```

Output:

```
[1] " "                   "coif"                " ter"               
 [4] " "                   "plushy"              "no hat"             
 [7] "what"                "hat no"              " "                  
[10] "HAT, what"           "what, hat, no, hats" "A water  "
```